# Do you pay verification fees in an exchange?

Tags: transaction-fees

In an exchange of cryptocurrencies (say an exchange of ETH to BTC on poloniex or kraken), do you still pay a fee to the miners to verify the transaction(s) or is it included in the exchange fees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That exchange takes place entirely on the exchange's books. Miners don't verify those transactions. Someone will pay transaction fees when you deposit or withdraw to and from the exchange.